# SQL Returning Second Client Visit Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
Client_no   First_Visit    Receipt_no   TransactionDate
**1020634   2/24/2014 0:00  1350436     3/8/2014**
1020634     2/24/2014 0:00  1350530     3/9/2014
1020634     2/24/2014 0:00  1350760     3/10/2014
1020634     2/24/2014 0:00  1350891     3/11/2014
1020635     2/24/2014 0:00  1347544     2/24/2014
1020635     2/24/2014 0:00  1347551     2/24/2014
1020636     2/24/2014 0:00  1347553     2/24/2014
1020636     2/24/2014 0:00  1347555     2/24/2014
1020636     2/24/2014 0:00  1347554     2/24/2014
**1020636   2/24/2014 0:00  1348904     3/1/2014**
1020636     2/24/2014 0:00  1349662     3/5/2014
1020637     2/24/2014 0:00  1347596     2/24/2014
**1020637   2/24/2014 0:00  1348073     2/26/2014**
1020638     2/25/2014 0:00  1347690     2/25/2014
1020638     2/25/2014 0:00  1355142     3/22/2014
1020638     2/25/2014 0:00  1355132     3/22/2014
1020639     2/25/2014 0:00  1347749     2/25/2014
**1020639   2/25/2014 0:00  641852      2/26/2014**
1020639     2/25/2014 0:00  641846      2/26/2014
1020639     2/25/2014 0:00  641966      2/27/2014
```

I have the date of the clients first visit. I want, in a new column, to return the date when they visit a second time -- date of second visit following their first visit.

** ** = the second visit of that client

Working

RANK () OVER PARTITION did the trick. RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY b.client_no ORDER BY Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) ASC) Visit

In WHERE I removed all dates that were equal to First_Visit to avoid the RANK from doubling and jumping from 1 to 3.

QUERY

```
Select c.Client_no, c.First_Visit, c.ticket_no, c.Date Second_Visit 
From (Select b.Client_no,b.First_Visit,  a.ticket_no, 
Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) Date, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY b.client_no ORDER BY
Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) ASC)Visit 
From Transactions_01 a
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Client_no, Convert(date,first_Visit)First_Visit FROM Clients
Where First_Visit > DATEADD(D,-31,GETDATE()))  b on a.client_no = b.client_no
Where a.Last_Mdt > DATEADD(D,-31,GETDATE()) AND Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) 
<>  B.First_Visit  AND A.Status=1

Group By b.Client_no,b.First_Visit,  a.ticket_no, Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) )  c
WHERE  Visit =1 Order By c.Client_no,c.Date
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server MS

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Post your attempt in the question itself.

Comment: RANK () OVER PARTITION did the trick. RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY b.client_no ORDER BY Convert(date,a.Last_Mdt) ASC) Visit

Comment: Wait wait wait. You're not storing your data with those **'s are you?

Comment: No, @Zane. That was indicator to show the desired results.

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I'm not very familiar with formatting here.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column in your database with a ALTER TABLE command (refer to the documentation of your database provider).

Then you must change the application that is writing into this database to write in the new column and not a new line in the table.

If your want the new column as a result of a query you can use auto join. SOmething like : (need to be improved to return exactly what you want)

```
SELECT t1.Client_no, t1.First_Visit, t1.Receipt_no, t1.TransactionDate, t2.First_Visit
FROM my_log_table t1, my_log_table t2
WHERE t1.Client_no = t2.Client_no
```

If your database provider supports it, you can use concate with a group. For example for mysql :

```
SELECT Client_no, GROUP_CONCAT(Receipt_no SEPARATOR ' ') , GROUP_CONCAT(TransactionDate SEPARATOR ' '), GROUP_CONCAT(First_Visit SEPARATOR ' ') FROM my_log_table GROUP BY Client_no;
```

This solution also have to be improved to fit your needs.

Comment: What if he eventually needs other visits?  This table could end up with dozens of `NULL` `N_Visit` columns, which is poor design.

Comment: The request was "a new column". But you are right maybe it was a new result column of a query. I'll edit

Comment: Yes, a new result column. I can't actually right to any tables.